# show value for 5 seconds, then reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

By clicking 'show jackpot', I want the value to be shown in place of the button for five seconds, then revert back to the original state.

I cannot get the button to revert back to its original state, can anyone help?

Would I need to reset the state in `componentWillUnmount`?

```
componentDidMount: function() {

this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
  this.setState({
    data: result
  });}.bind(this));
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
 },
```

I have this as an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mharrisweb/pss04s5L/56/)

Something like this?

```
    setState: function() {
    this.setState({
            clicked: !this.state.clicked
       }, this.delayState());
    },

    delayState: function() {
        setTimeout((function() {
           this.setState({ 
           clicked: !this.state.clicked
           )}
        }).bind(this), 2000);
      },

      handleClick: function(event) {
        this.setState();
      },
```

Comment: The code you've added in an update is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have i structured my functions right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState` callback function. So you initially set you state and set a timer on callback with updates the state again.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html